# Need to insert random numbers of 1-100 into a three dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to create a program in which random numbers between 1 and 100 are placed in each dimension of a 3D array. The arrays are of varying sizes, and thus far have only encountered crashes upon execution. Tried on a smaller scale with a 1D array and got it to work fine. Cant seem to translate on larger scale. My code so far...

```
int const STOCK_AMOUNT = 1000, DAY_AMOUNT = 366, TIME_AMOUNT = 480;
int randomGenerator();
void randomInsert(int array0[DAY_AMOUNT][TIME_AMOUNT][STOCK_AMOUNT]);

int main()
{
    int cube[DAY_AMOUNT][TIME_AMOUNT][STOCK_AMOUNT];
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    randomInsert(cube);
    return 0;
}

void randomInsert(int array0[DAY_AMOUNT][TIME_AMOUNT][STOCK_AMOUNT])
{
    for (int count1 = 0; count1 < DAY_AMOUNT; count1++)
    {
        for (int count2 = 0; count2 < TIME_AMOUNT; count2++)
        {
            for (int count3 = 0; count3 < STOCK_AMOUNT; count3++)
            {
                int randomGenerator();
                array0[count1][count2][count3] = randomGenerator();
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    }   
}

int randomGenerator()
{
    int randNum;
    int lowerLimit = 1;
    int upperLimit = 100;
    randNum = (rand() % upperLimit) + lowerLimit;
    return randNum;
}
```

Comment: Your inner loop probably does not need the cout statement.  (366,000 * 480 linefeeds!)  And, while you are at it, please describe what you think the output of running your program should be?

Comment: Also in the inner loop, you do not need to forward declare the randomGenerator() function, already done at the top of your code

Comment: so the array was way too big after reading some comments and further inquiry with the professor.stock_amount=100 day_amount=50 time_amount=8. Basically an                                                                           olap cube[Stock_amount][day_amount][time_amount]

Comment: The output once said and done should insert random prices 1-100 into the 3-d array. Then calculate the average price of each stock for every day of the given period (50), then write the output of the averages to the given file with 100 rows for the stocks and 50 columns for the days.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be exceeding stack size. your array, created on the stack, holds about 175M integers, that is, about 700MB of memory. You need to setup compilation options to increase the stack size.

EDIT: moreover, please be aware that putting such huge arrays on the stack is generally considered bad practice. Ideally, use STL vectors, that is the modern way to deal with arrays.

Comment: @bames53 true, but that is another debate. For sure STL would be a more "modern" approach that inteernally moves the array to the heap, but this answer was a specific assessment to the presented code. I added this remark to the answer to consider your remark . :)

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a more complex version using the STL:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <ctime>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

// The size of a type that can hold values from 1 to 100.  Used for storage.  (Copy to int for calculation.)
using elem_t = int_least8_t;
// Lower and upper bounds:
constexpr int lb = 1;
constexpr int ub = 100;

constexpr size_t stocks = 100, days = 300, times = 400;
using pricearray_t = elem_t[days][times][stocks];

pricearray_t& init_prices()
/* Returns a heap-allocated array that must be deleted with delete[]. */
{
  // This ugly little cast is brought to us by the C++ rules for array types.
  pricearray_t &to_return = *(pricearray_t*) new pricearray_t;
  const std::default_random_engine::result_type seed = std::time(NULL) * CLOCKS_PER_SEC + std::clock();
  std::default_random_engine generator(seed);
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int_fast8_t> distribution( lb, ub );

  auto x = std::bind( distribution, generator );

  for ( size_t i = 0; i < days; ++i )
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < times; ++j )
      for ( size_t k = 0; k < stocks; ++k )
        to_return[i][j][k] = static_cast<elem_t>(x());

  return to_return;
}

int main(void)
{
  const pricearray_t &prices = init_prices();

  long long int sum = 0;
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < days; ++i )
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < times; ++j )
      for ( size_t k = 0; k < stocks; ++k ) {
        const int x = prices[i][j][k];
        assert( x >= lb );
        assert( x <= ub );
        sum += x;
      }

   cout << "The mean is " << static_cast<double>(sum) / days / times / stocks << "." << endl;

  delete[] &prices;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here’s a version that uses smart pointers to manage memory automatically:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <ctime>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <random>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

// The size of a type that can hold values from 1 to 100.  Used for storage.  (Copy to int for calculation.)
using elem_t = int_least8_t;
// Lower and upper bounds:
constexpr int lb = 1;
constexpr int ub = 100;

constexpr size_t stocks = 100, days = 300, times = 400;
// The unique_ptr type doesn’t play nicely with arrays of known size.
using pricearray_t = elem_t[][times][stocks];

std::unique_ptr<pricearray_t> init_prices()
/* Returns a managed pointer to an array of uniformly-distributed values.
 */
{
  // This smart pointer will use its move constructor to avoid copying the entire array.
  std::unique_ptr<pricearray_t> to_return = std::make_unique<pricearray_t>(days);
  const std::default_random_engine::result_type seed = std::time(NULL) * CLOCKS_PER_SEC + std::clock();
  std::default_random_engine generator(seed);
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int_fast8_t> distribution( lb, ub );
  auto x = std::bind( distribution, generator );

  for ( size_t i = 0; i < days; ++i )
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < times; ++j )
      for ( size_t k = 0; k < stocks; ++k )
        to_return[i][j][k] = static_cast<elem_t>(x());

  return to_return;
}

int main(void)
{
 /* The contents of the smart pointer will be deleted automatically when it goes out of scope.
  */
  const std::unique_ptr<pricearray_t> prices = init_prices();

  long long int sum = 0;
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < days; ++i )
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < times; ++j )
      for ( size_t k = 0; k < stocks; ++k ) {
        const int x = prices[i][j][k];
        assert( x >= lb );
        assert( x <= ub );
        sum += x;
      }

   cout << "The mean is " << static_cast<double>(sum) / days / times / stocks << "." << endl;

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 }
```

Comment: This is a good example of how to use C++11 and onward effectively. +1!

Comment: @ZirconiumHacker Thank you.  I’ve added a version that uses smart pointers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the specifications for the original cube provided by the professor were clearly much too large....odd how a professor wouldnt catch that? Scaled back the specs, and now have something that works. The bit in the main is supposed to find the average of the stock price each day(50) for each stock(100).

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
const int STOCK_AMOUNT = 100, DAY_AMOUNT = 50, TIME_AMOUNT = 8;
int randomGenerator();
void priceGenerator(int [STOCK_AMOUNT][DAY_AMOUNT][TIME_AMOUNT]);


int main()
{
ofstream outputFile;
int cube[STOCK_AMOUNT][DAY_AMOUNT][TIME_AMOUNT];
double total;
srand((unsigned)time(0));
priceGenerator(cube);
outputFile.open("Average_Day_Price");
for (int row = 0; row < STOCK_AMOUNT; row++)
{   
total=0;
for (int col = 0; col < DAY_AMOUNT; col++)
{       
for (int layer = 0; layer < TIME_AMOUNT; layer++)
{           
total = cube[row][col][layer];
double average = (total / TIME_AMOUNT);
outputFile << "STOCK Id:" << (row+1) << "--" << "--" << average <<endl:             
}
}
}
outputFile.close();
return 0;
}
void priceGenerator(int array0[STOCK_AMOUNT][DAY_AMOUNT][TIME_AMOUNT])
{
int i,y, z;
for ( i = 0; i < STOCK_AMOUNT; i++)
{
for ( y = 0; y < DAY_AMOUNT; y++)
{
for (z = 0; z < TIME_AMOUNT; z++)       
{
int randNum;
int lowerLimit = 1;
int upperLimit = 100;
randNum = (rand() % upperLimit) + lowerLimit;
array0[i][y][z] = randNum;          
}
}
}
}
```